# updated value for generic hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this hook

```
export const useLegalFooter = ({ customContent, isOpenOnPageLoad = false }) => {
const dispatch = useContext(LegalFooterDispatchContext);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ customContent, isOpenOnPageLoad });

  return () => {
    dispatch({ customContent: null, isOpenOnPageLoad: false });
  };
}, [customContent, dispatch, isOpenOnPageLoad]);
};
```

and the way I use it is

```
useLegalFooter({
  isOpenOnPageLoad: !showModalLoader,
  customContent: renderQuoteAndPurchaseDisclaimers(policyType),
});
```

However, I noticed when the showModalLoader is updated the hook doesn't get an updated value for isOpenonPageLoad.
for example, showModalLoader is true when the component mounts, and then it changes to false. but still, the footer is showing open.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can we see the `LegalFooterDispatchContext`?

Comment: export const LegalFooterDispatchContext = createContext(null);

Comment: How is your `dispatch` function supposed to be interacting with this?